# Create div above other div only with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I need create a div above another div, but I dont have access to the css file, thus everything needs to be done via JavaScript.

**This is my wrong code:**

```
var div = document.getElementById("down"); 
var divAbove = document.createElement("div");

    divAbove.id = "up";
    divAbove.style.background = "red";
    divAbove.style.position = "absolute";
    divAbove.style.width = "150px"
    div.appendChild(divAbove );
```

I can't see the new div.

Comment: any error in the javascript console? is `divAbov` a typo?

Comment: typo... 4th line. " divAbov." instead of " divAbove."... look mom, no "e"

Comment: Sorry, this code is only an example, i write it here, in my file is writed ok.

Comment: please, open the javascript console, look at any messages in there and write them on your question, thank you.

Comment: You probably can’t expect to see much of an element as long as it is still 0 px high …

Answer (score 3):

If you can pinpoint the container element you can make use of `.insertBefore()`

[More Info (docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container"); 
var div = document.getElementById("down"); 

var divAbove = document.createElement("div");
    divAbove.id = "up";
    divAbove.style.backgroundColor  = "red";
    divAbove.style.width = "110px"
    divAbove.style.height = "60px"
    divAbove.innerHTML = "Added via JS"

    container.insertBefore(divAbove, div);
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='down' style='height: 60px; width: 110px; background-color: yellow'>
     Existing element 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This work.

```
var div = document.getElementById("down"); 
var divAbove=document.createElement("div");
divAbove.id = "up";
divAbove.style.background = "red";
divAbove.style.position = "absolute";
divAbove.style.width = "150px";     
divAbove.style.height= "150px";
div.appendChild(divAbove);
```

Answer (score -1):

From this point I would say that the div is there, but due to a typo in `divAbov.style.background = "red";` it does not have a visible background. Try fixing the typo.

If the problem persists, please post your console log if there is any errors in there.

Comment: Please see stackoverflow guidelines. Your answer should be useful for other users too. Flag the question as out of topic for typos.

Comment: the div is not appended, since the javascript error stops the interpreter on that line

Answer (score -1):

The reason you can't see new `div` is that you didn't give any body to it. For example, it may be a case to write before appending `divAbove` the following:

```
divAbove.innerHTML = "Hello World";
```